# RTL is forced in RTL devices

Tags: android, react-native, expo, right-to-left

The new version of React Native has issued support for RTL devices:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html
However, it seems that in RTL android devices the RTL layout is forced and there's no way to change it so now all apps are broken for RTL devices.
How can I force my app to use LTR?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding to `MainApplication.java`:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // FORCE LTR
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: adding to which file?

Comment: in MainApplication.java file

Comment: This works great! ... (setting the supportsRtl="false" in the manifest did nothing for me).

Comment: I've written a small gist that helps with this issue at https://medium.com/@nirlevy/rtl-support-in-react-native-even-for-non-rtl-applications-981359ee7c46

Comment: Fantastic. Worked great for me.

Comment: the same issue happening in iOS also. @atlanteh do you have any solution for iOS?

Comment: what if i using expo?how can i access this file?

Comment: I18nUtil is imported from 'import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;'

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Expo or bare React Native, put these lines in your `App.js/tsx` file:

```js
import { I18nManager} from 'react-native';

I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(false);

const App = () => {

   ~ ~ ~

}
```

Comment: Adding those two worked for me : `I18nManager.forceRTL(false);` and `I18nManager.allowRTL(false);`

Answer (score 8):

In manifest.xml file add `android:supportsRtl="false"` to your application tag

Comment: yes, this answer and also the one above (allowRTL-false) did the magic.

Comment: You need to add `android:tools`:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.*.*"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

...

    <application
      android:supportsRtl="false"
      tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
...

`

Comment: there is not `manifest.xml ` in my project. where i search for that?

Answer (score 5):

**simply by adding these lines of code in your project entry point** e.g `App.tsx`

```
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";

// disable RTL
try {
  I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
  I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
  // the next line is the most effective one
  I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(false);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

#### UPDATE

to overcome the current situation for **"now"**, because even though with these settings rtl is still forced!!!.

you have to change every `flexDirection: "row"` with

```
flexDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
```

Answer (score 3):

@atlanteh's answer is right.
I am just giving you a detailed answer for those who have the ios background and not much aware of the Android.

first, try once. if 1st one does not work then try 2. If still not work then try both. then it will show expected output.

**Answer 1**

**MainApplication.java**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // FORCE LTR
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
        ....
    }
}
```

**Answer 2**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

i have add the  `android:supportsRtl="false"` in `application` tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.appname">
    ........
    <application 
      android:supportsRtl="false"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
       ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```