# How to handle both Arabic and English data viewed in my React native project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am targeting both Android and iOS, and both Arabic and English language and i am new to React native development and unfortunately i faced a strange behavior when i try to convert system language from Arabic to English on Android (as the first app release will be on Arabic only) and also when user try to register with his name written in English or try to add post in English the data is viewed in the opposite side make the component seems weird.

Login page when system language is Arabic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNOYB.png)

Login page when i try to convert system language to English:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAzRr.png)

News Feed page when system language is Arabic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht8W3.png)

News Feed page when i try to convert system language to English:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQN63.png)

I have a feel that my start with jsx coding was incorrect as i start coding and testing and emulator language was in Arabic and when i tried to test on iOS i found the same result as what i have found when convert language to Arabic on Android (as shown above...)
so if any one can help me figure out where is my mistake and how to handle Arabic and English with out loosing my layout.

Comment: See this:https://blog.callstack.io/react-native-handling-language-changes-on-android-the-right-way-c883056a8f5c

Comment: Also this :https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps

Comment: Did you try to set textAlign style? also, if you want to disable this behaviour when changing system language, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815309/rtl-is-forced-in-rtl-devices) answer.

Comment: @i_th thanks for reply ... i read this article https://blog.callstack.io/react-native-handling-language-changes-on-android-the-right-way-c883056a8f5c and react native blog but sorry for saying that for now i can't figure out how to handle both English and Arabic in the same layout when system language is English and when converted to Arabic and how to handle any strange behavior that i might face between both RTL and LTR and how to handle iOS as it seems different.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed this how to deal with RTL and LTR :https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps

Comment: @Dror Bar thanks for reply ... how might textAlign help me in my situation? i already tested it but text is viewed in other direction when changing the system language and regarding the link you provided how it might affect RTL and  LTR as i have to use both Arabic and English language in my app.

Comment: @i_th but what i get when i read about RTL and LTR is  that react native already support that and i don't have to add any thing is that right and what about iOS?!.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed Read the article. It is for both `[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];`