# Expo rtl disable for a component and all children

Tags: react-native, internationalization, expo

I know you can use I18nManager to make the app rtl but some libraries do not support it and it makes them look weird.On the other hand if I disable it and go and make the app all by myself and make it rtl with my own functions.

Still, they are some library which do support it and that’s the only way to make them rtl.

How is it possible to disable the rtl for a specific component, but keep it for the rest.

Maybe like a whitelist and blacklist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RTL is forced in RTL devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815309/rtl-is-forced-in-rtl-devices)

Comment: refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065301/4846859)

Comment: Thank you but no it doesn't, this is currently impossible as it seems

Comment: I just tried the answer I posted [refer to this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065301/4846859) and it was working.

Comment: No it doesn't do why I'm talking about, what I'm saying in that to keep a portion of Dom rtl and another portion ltr which can happen in Html but not in react native yet, and maybe even never would happen.